# How to resolve System Argument exception errors in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I get an error because of the file path declared here:

```
private UIImageRes onClickImage = new UIImageRes(@"..\..\Resources\check_active.png",new Rectangle());
```

However, when I declare the actual path, it works, i.e.

```
private UIImageRes onClickImage = new UIImageRes(@"C:\Desktop\File\Resources\check_active.png",new Rectangle());
```

Now, this code is of a separate project which I am adding to my new project. I don't think its a good idea to put the exact file path there. I shall have to change all the file paths in multiple source codes. Also, the project won't work if I copy it to another folder. What should I do about this?

EDIT:

I am completely new to C#, and have some academic experience in C++ and java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**:

If you want a fixed path to be used by both project then you can use **INI file** to store the path. This would help to change the path later without changing source code.

**Solution 2**:

Use [Application.StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build a Path.

For example:

```
string sRelativePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Resources\check_active.png");
private UIImageRes onClickImage = new UIImageRes(sRelativePath,new Rectangle());
```

**Application.StartupPath** gives the path for the executable file that started the application, not including the executable name.

**UPDATE**:

Let's suppose `Project1.exe` is located here:

```
C:\Desktop\File\Project1.exe
```

Application.StartupPath returns :

```
C:\Desktop\File
```

When  you use this:

```
string sRelativePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Resources\check_active.png");
```

Output will be in `sRelativePath` string:

```
C:\Desktop\File\Resources\check_active.png
```

Comment: So, I should put `Application.StartupPath` in the argument?

Comment: You will get path of your currently running executable. You can use it in the argument.

Comment: I get an error
`The name 'Path' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: It requires `using System.IO` namespace. Actually this solution doesn't solve your issue. If  you have fixed path for all projects.

Comment: I am basically trying to use an existing project in my new project. The problem with the file path is occurring in the existing project. The compiler can't resolve `"..\..\Resources\check_active.png"`. So, I gave the exact path and it worked.

What do people do in such cases?
When I use your solution, I get a .dll file missing error.

Comment: `..\..\Resources\check_active.png` by this you mean two levels up?

Comment: Yes, but that code gives a System Argument exception

Comment: use of .. is not supported by C#

Comment: I resolved the issue. I gave the following argument:

`"Main\Sub\Sub1\Resources\filename.jpg"`

Now, I think the code will run irrespective of where it is placed in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got this error when I am working with image processing using C#. Then, I copied the required dll's in the bin folder of the project and the problem is solved. For example, cudart32_55.dll is one of the required dll's for image processing. I did not include this dll and tried to run the code, then I got System.Argument exception. So, please make sure that you are placing all the required dll's to get rid of System.Arguments Exception.

This worked for me and this is what I experienced. I suggest you to try it once.